# Defining String Arrarys

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm a  beginner in Javascript and somethinh strange occured.

I wanted to create an global String array in an external Javascript file with
`var natArray = new Array(20);` But my IDE(Webstorm 7) Says me newArray is an Unresolved function and I cant use the array in another function it was created for(Source: Javascript Console)

Thank you for your time and feedback.

EDIT: Rest of the Code

```
function country(name){

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        natArray[i]=name;


    document.write(natArray[i]);

}
```

And here i call it(a html file):

```
            Country:
        <select>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            country("RandomCountry1");
            country("RandomCountry2");

            </script>
        </select>
```

Im just getting an empty drop-down-list

Comment: `newArray` is _undefined_, you probably meant `new Array`

Comment: yeah already changed it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the reason that `document.write(natArray[i]);` is returning `undefined` is that you are leaking `i` to the global scope in `for(i=0;i<20;i++)`.

Once this loop has completed, `i` is equal to `20`, even outside the scope of the loop (to avoid this, try `for(var i=0;i<20;i++)`. Although `natArray` has a `.length` of `20`, arrays elements are zero-indexed, meaning that they start counting at 0, not 1.

Because of this, if what you are trying to do is access the last element of `natArray`, you can/should do so with `natArray[natArray.length - 1]`. The `-1` accounts for the zero-indexed nature of Javascript arrays. If `natArray` has a length of `20`, you will fail to access `natArray[20]` because this statement is actually trying to access the 21st element, not the 20th.

Comment: now i understand what ive been doing wrong! thanks